# REST service sending corrupted file

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create a java REST service that will download a word doc.  The file downloads but the contents are just garbage hex, not the actual Word doc contents.  My sample code is below.  What am I missing?  The before & after files have the same amount of bytes.

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
@RequestMapping(value = "get/testdoc", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/octet-stream)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<byte[]>  getTestDoc() throws Throwable{ 

    File doc = new File("C:\\temp\\file.doc");

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(doc);
    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();  
    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    responseHeaders.set("Content-Disposition" , "Attachment; filename=file.doc");
    responseHeaders.setContentLength(ProposalDoc.length());



    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(bytes, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: How did you determine that the downloaded file is "garbage hex"? Did you try to open it with Word? Additionally it would be helpful to specify which version of Spring you are using.

Comment: What if you don't specify the octet stream and content length?

Comment: I opened the file in word.  Using Spring 3.1.1.  does this need to be Base64 encoded prior to download?

Comment: You should be using a `FileSystemResource` instead of `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help.  I ended up bypassing Spring & attaching the file to the response, as listed in the code below.  I'm suspecting that sprint was converting the bytes somehow behind the scenes.  I looked into configuring the ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter, but that didn't seem to help. This is good enough for me, for now.

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
@RequestMapping(value = "get/doc", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/octet-stream")
   public  HttpEntity  getProposalDocs(HttpServletResponse response) throws Throwable{ 
        File doc = new File("C:\\temp\\file.doc");

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(doc);

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"test.doc\"");
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream;");
        StreamUtils.copy(is ,response.getOutputStream());

        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two problems:

**1. The Length Header:**

I my opinion there is at least one very strange line:

```
responseHeaders.setContentLength(ProposalDoc.length());
```

I think, it should be:

```
responseHeaders.setContentLength(bytes.length);
```

**2. `@ResponseBody` Annotation**

If you use return type `ResponseEntity<byte[]>`, then you must NOT add `@ResponseBody`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "get/testdoc", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]>  getTestDoc() throws Throwable{ 
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Mr Smith: have a look at the second problem

Comment: Thanks.  I removed the @ResponseBody annotation, but I have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace  produces="application/octet-stream")
with produces="application/vnd.ms-word")

Comment: and the file opens ok before download ? the files that is in location: C:\\temp\\file.doc ?

Comment: Yes.  the file opens fine before download.  Some encoding issue maybe?

Comment: I read the file into and byte array & wrote it back out on the server side & there was no issue.  Something is going wrong when transmitting it

Answer (score 0):

Check this code also, it works fine with me.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/get/doc" , method = RequestMethod.GET , 
    produces = "application/msword")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getProposalDocs() throws IOException{
    ClassPathResource docfile = new ClassPathResource("file.doc");
    HttpHeaders headers

 = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
            headers.add("Expires", "0");
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentLength(docfile.contentLength())
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/msword"))
                .body(new InputStreamResource(docfile.getInputStream()));
    }
```

EDITED: the idea that worked with me to return InputStreamResource instead of byte[].
Also specify the content type as produces="application/octet-stream".

This works fine with me without needed to bypass servlet response..

Comment: add some text to explain how your answer solve OP current problem and help others which have same issue.Thanks